# ¿Cuál es el mejor formato para realizar operaciones con fechas en javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, ionic3

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación móvil con el Framework Ionic 3.
necesito realizar operaciones con las fechas tales como: 
**¿Cuantos días laborables hay entre dos fechas?**

***Nota: Días Laborables-> Lunes a Viernes***

Si me pueden recomendar cual sería el formato de la fecha o alguna librería que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno si entendí tu pregunta, realmente desconozco librerias, pero a mano te muestro lo siguiente:

```js
var findeSemanas = 8;
/* 8 días ocurre en todos los meses, ya que todos los meses tienen mínimo
28 días, entonces 7*4 = 28 dias, 4 son las semanas, pero como cada semana tiene 2 findesemanas,
2 findesemanas * 4 semanas = 8 dias, a esto le sumare los dias que tiene el mes contando desde 28,
entonces diciembre por ejemplo tiene 31 dias, esto entonces son 3 días mas que 28 (31-28=3), entonces serían 23 dias laborales..
Por qué? porque 28-8 = 20 + 3(dias de diciembre), entonces como base, en cualquier mes tienes como mínimo 20 días. */

var año = [
  {mes:'diciembre',diasLaborales:23,dias: []},
  {mes:'noviembre',diasLaborales:22,dias: []}
];

for(var i=0;i<año.length;i++){
  for(var j=1; j <= año[i].diasLaborales;j++) {
        año[i].dias[j] = j;    
  }
}

for(var e = 0; e<año.length;e++){
  console.log(`El mes de ${año[e].mes} tiene ${año[e].diasLaborales} dias laborales.`);
}

for(var k = 1; k<=año[0].diasLaborales;k++){
  console.log(`Hay ${k - año[0].dias[1]} dias laborales, entre el ${k} de ${año[0].mes} y ${año[0].dias[1]} de ${año[0].mes}`);
}
```